# HTTP Client component for C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, dll, httpclient

I am looking for Http Client for C#.

It must:

1. Support IPv6, Socks5, HTTPS proxy (both IPv4, IPv6).
2. Be stable and with strong support frequently updating.
3. Allow to get all cookies to XML or other format and set cookies back.
4. Allow to set cookies from Header string.
5. Allow to do custom requests (with custom
   content-type).
6. Be light and work fast.
7. It would be great if the same company has Mail and SFTP component.

Could you please recommend something? I can buy if it worth the price.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Answer (score 0):

There is one built into the framework which I think provides all the features you've listed.

[System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: It doesn't support Socks5 proxy.

Answer (score -1):

You can give [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) a try. It's a C# wrapper over [Cef](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef), a project that embeds a Chromium-based browser within an application. I haven't done much with it, so I don't know if it satisfies all your conditions, but it's based on Chromium so it's worth a shot.